How to block iframe popup from external link
I'm using an iframe to embed an external videos. The problem is that when I click play button it is showing several times irrevelant popups pages with 18+ content until video start.
In order to block the popups I was using the iframe in sandbox mode like this:
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="https://footballvid.com/yourvideo45"></iframe>
and it was working perfectly fine until today I get error message that embeded videos are not working anymore in iframe with sandbox tag and have to remove the sandbox.
Is there any other method similar with the sandbox tag to embed video and block annoying popups ?
I try to use iframe in sandbox mode but it's not working anymore

The video provider wants incentives...

It shows a 404 error when trying out your code. What is the actual URL to the video?
